# How do I install the Mirage Image viewer on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 to solve a Bluetooth issue and the Mirage image viewer is not available in the depository. I use it a lot to quickly rotate and crop images and my fingers automatically go to the relevant keys so I would rather not have to get used to another application.

Can someone provide instructions to install it please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install Mirage's package with dependencies [from 19.10 repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/mirage) by executing:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/mirage
cd ~/Downloads/mirage

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/exiv2/libexiv2-14_0.25-4ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pyexiv2/python-pyexiv2_0.3.2-9_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mirage/mirage_0.9.5.2-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```